# Terminal can't find img file of Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, laptop, usb-drive, mac

On a Mac, I followed the steps for the '**USB download from Mac**', but on Step 9: Execute

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/diskN bs=1m
```

(replace `/path/to/downloaded.img` with the path where the image file is located; for example, `./ubuntu.img` or `./ubuntu.dmg`).

When I replace `/path/to/downloaded.img` with the `ubuntu.img` file (I converted the iso file into a `img.dmg` file, then to a `img` file) and press Enter, the Terminal just comes up with:

```
ubuntu.img;file or directory not found.
```

Any reasons why this might be happening?

Comment: Make sure your path is correct. Declaring only `ubuntu.img` works only if you are in the folder where that file is saved. Otherwise you have to specify to absolute (full) path to the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a boot-able Live Ubuntu USB installer then i suggest you try this software : [UNetBootIn software :](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)